# iPhone game development

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am new to the iPhone game development. How can I develop a simple game by using cocoa2D. and I want to know more about Cocoa2D.

Comment: First I think I know why you're having trouble finding information about Cocos2D, because it's not Cocoa2D. Second, where to get started questions are off topic. See the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) about what kind of questions to ask. Your question will be closed. But you can try [these tutorials](http://www.iphonegametutorials.com/tutorials/#beginner).

Comment: You should have a concrete question and then come come here.

Comment: I wonder why people post questions like: I wanna know how the Universe works. Leaving out question marks and stating the most general issue.. and expecting an answer that's different from `42`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

How To Make A Simple iPhone Game with Cocos2D Tutorial
http://www.raywenderlich.com/352/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-tutorial

Comment: Answers that are just a link to somewhere aren't very good answers if the link goes dead. You're generally expected to say _something_ in your answer other than just giving the link so that your answer is still useful if the link dies.